# highchart custom menu with when i drilldown and drillup custom event (contextmenu) not working

Tags: highcharts, drilldown, custom-events

I am using highchart contextmenu (using: https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/js/customEvents.js) and drill down and drill up.

**Problem:**

When I right click on pie chart we are able to call alert which is in contextmenu. At the same time, when I drill down and drill up then right click on pie chart, contextmenu is not working. In plotoption it's working fine but I do not need it in plotoption.

Code:

```
chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
        drillup: function () {
            var chart = this;
            window['chart'] = chart;
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('drillup',chart.series[0].events);

                if (!chart.plotOptions){
                    chart.plotOptions = {};
                }

                if (!chart.plotOptions.series) {
                        chart.plotOptions.series = {};
                }
                if (!chart.plotOptions.series.events) {
                    chart.plotOptions.series['events'] = {                   
                        contextmenu: function () {
                            alert('hi33')
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        events: {                   
                            contextmenu: function () {
                                alert('hi33')
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                */
                console.log('drillup222',chart);
            }, 100);
        },
        drilldown: function (e) {
            var chart = this;
            window['chart'] = chart;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (!chart.series[0].events) {
                    chart.series[0]['events'] = {                   
                        contextmenu: function () {
                           alert('hi33')
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log('drilldown',chart.series[0]);
            }, 100);
        }
    }
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k14ajzpo/2/
https://jsfiddle.net/0txqk2cn/1/

Comment: Formatted code sections, fixed grammar/spelling

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this issue is to add an event to plotOptions and check if event occurred on main series. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
      load: function () {
        var chart = this;

        chart.series[0].customEventsEnabled = true;
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      events: {
        contextmenu: function() {
          var series = this;

          if (series.customEventsEnabled || series.drilldownLevel) {
            console.log('working');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pLqvmky/